# How to use AJAX with HTML for multiple values of href of HTML

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

How can I link HTML href values to AJAX so that I get result on same page but in different conatainer. Below is my my code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>DTC Search</title>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.0/jquery.min.js"          type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#a').click(function() {
                e.preventDefault();
                $('content').load($(this).attr('href'));
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <a href="" target="_blank">CT1<br></a>
    <a href="" target="_blank">CT2<br></a>      
    <a href="" target="_blank">CT3<br></a>
    <a href="" target="_blank">CT4<br></a>
    <div id="sidebar"> Body</div>
    <div id="footer"> &nbsp; </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Since I am new to AJAX, I am not able to understand how to get information related to clicked value of href in AJAX function so that it will display result in same page but in other division. My filename is, say front_end.php

Comment: Err… what do you think the `$(this).attr('href')` bit is all about?

Comment: `$('#a')` is invalid, because there's no element with `id="a"`.

Comment: What should be there in place of * in ajax function?

Comment: I do accept answer.. I said thanks too.

Answer (score 1):

This is your code, just updated:

```
<html>
<head> <title>DTC Search</title>
 <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.0/jquery.min.js"          type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
  $('a').each(function(){ 
      $(this).on("click",function(e) {

        console.log(e);
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#content').load($(this).attr('href'));
      });
   });

  });
  </script>

  <a href="front_end.php" target="_blank">CT1<br></a>
<a href="front_end.php" target="_blank">CT2<br></a>      
<a href="front_end.php" target="_blank">CT3<br></a>
<a href="front_end.php" target="_blank">CT4<br></a>

   <div id="sidebar"> Body
  </div> <div id="content"></div>
 <div id="footer"> &nbsp; </div>
 </body>
 </html>
```

1) A tag is not `$("#a")` in jquery

2) `$('content')` is nothing

3) element with id `$('#content')` or some element with class $('#content')

Tako a look at [jsBin example](http://jsfiddle.net/74Ffy/)

[1](http://jsfiddle.net/74Ffy/): http://jsbin.com/IFaLoJE/1/ or [jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/74Ffy/)

Comment: You might have a good reason for it but I see the `$.each()` as redundant when all that is needed is `$('a').on('click', function(){})`.

Comment: Thanks but, the result is going in different page rather than printing it in same page with above code.

Comment: @user2818537 code was little bit wrong, i have updated code now and added two examples.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this :

```
$('a').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#content').load(this.href);
});
```